# SSO between microsoft teams and my website

Tags: single-sign-on, integration, microsoft-teams

I need information about sso in case if i want make single sign in to my education website using microsoft account for student.

I mean i want to make a integration between schools and my website, schhols use microsoft teams so i want a single sign on to my website throw account of microsoft teams.

```
Its possible ? or no
```

Comment: You should probably start here https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/identity/add-sign-in-with-microsoft

Comment: Yes, it is possible. More info https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/manage-apps/what-is-single-sign-on

Answer (score 0):

@sam pilo,
Yes, you can implement by using [Single sign-on (SSO) support for tabs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/tabs/how-to/authentication/auth-aad-sso)